# Changing the processor on Toshiba R500 Portege?

Tags: cpu, upgrade, toshiba-laptop, portege-m400

This is my first post here. I am looking to fix my old Toshiba Portege R500 laptop. It fell in the water a while ago so I bought a new one. To my surprise, it still works, though it has a cracked screen and the battery doesn't work anymore. As such, I've decided to upgrade it. I just purchased a screen and am installing it as we speak, and I will purchase a new battery later on. I am also looking to upgrade the RAM and the processor. I am conversant with RAM upgrades in computers so that won't be much of a problem. The tricky thing, though, is the processor. It currently runs a one core Intel Centrino processor, and I'm wondering if I can change it. I know processor sets are soldered into most computers, but does anyone know if it would be possible to change the processor on a Portege?

Answer (score 2):

Most notebook processors are not soldered, they are socket type with a removable heatsink.

Most "netbooks" are permanently attached to the motherboard.

It is possible but is quite a task for a novice, there are also processor compatibility issues, you would need to know which ones it will support, even if the processor is the correct socket type it may not be supported by the Toshiba bios.

I don't think Toshiba releases user service manuals to the public so it makes it hard to know how to disassemble them to do major upgrades like a processor.

[Here is what Toshiba has to say about it](http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/TSB9401AX0001R01.htm)

[R500 dis-assembly video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOACz9pl4rU) does not look like an easy one to do.